# Indian passport Holder Travelling Los Angeles - Guangzhou - New Delhi with a 1.5 hour layover. Valid for Transit Without Visa?

Tags: visas, transit, china, china-southern-airlines, can

Apologies in advance if this question might have been asked multiple times.

I have a flight from Los Angeles to Guangzhou then a 1.5 hour layover and then Guangzhou to Delhi. I do not wish to leave the airport during this time.

I believe I am eligible for 24 Hour Transit without Visa as per https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm

Someone recently told me that this rule has changed. I contacted China Southern Airlines but they have asked me to call the immigration officials.

My flight is in a week, so I am not sure if I have the time to get the Transit Visa.

Can someone please confirm the latest on 24 hour transit without visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timatic, which is the database that airlines use to verify your travel documents, still states today that you can transit without a visa for a layover up to 24 hours.

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination. (SEE NOTE 88975)
>
> - This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC), Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Shenzhen (SZX), Urumqi (URC) and Yanji (YNJ).
>
> NOTE 88975: This TWOV facility does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (e.g. JFK - PVG - GUM).